Tag configuration option as required in IOptions
Using .net IOptions framework, is it possible to flag a particular value as required, such the application will not start if the value is not configured?
For instance if I were to make the Options class:
class MyOptions{
  public string OptionalOption { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public string RequiredOption { get;set; }
}

and bind with
services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("MyOptions"));

I would want the application to throw an exception if my appsettings.json contained only
{
  "MyOptions": {
    "OptionalOption": "foo"
  }
}

I can accomplish something similar by manually checking in every constructor that consumes IOptions<MyOptions> for if (myOptions.Value.RequiredOption == null), but I would prefer to not even make it that far.
Bonus: If I'm using [ConfigurationKeyName("REQUIRED_OPTION")], I would want the exception to read something along the lines of "Required configuration MyOptions:REQUIRED_OPTION not found in Configuration", as opposed to the actual property name in the class, which is "RequiredOption".

Compile-time options validation source generation?

by manually checking in every constructor - surely it would be easier to put such a check inside the property itself so that it blows up any time it's accessed, rather than put the check logic everywhere that accesses the property? Right click your property, refactor, convert to full property, then put a check and throw ahead of the the return

services
    .AddOptions<MyOptions>()
    .ValidateDataAnnotations()
    .ValidateOnStart()
    .Bind(Configuration.GetSection("MyOptions"));

Use AddOptions method which allows you to validate options with
ValidateDataAnnotations and ValidateOnStart extensions.

To retrieve your options in DI - simply expect an object of type IOptions<MyOptions> in the constructor, which has Value property containing your configured options.
